# Converting Older User Lookup to Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap

I am trying to port an LDAP authentication lookup configuration from an older installation to Apache 2.4. I do not have a good knowledge of LDAP.

All I get when I run a configtest is the error message:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 130 of /file_path/ldapdir.conf:
Bad LDAP URL while parsing.
*This is the line number of the end of the AuthLDAPURL*
What is wrong with that line?

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/docs/it/snaps">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Includes
        # Was
        # Order deny,allow
        # Deny from All
        Require all denied
        AuthName "Enter Your Netid and Password"
        AuthType basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        # Known obsolete directive
        # AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=sanitycheck, ou=Service, dc=example, dc=com"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxxxxxx"

        AuthLDAPURL     "ldaps://server1.example.com:1636\
                         ldaps://server2.example.com:1636\
                         ldaps://server3.example.com:1636\
                         ldaps://server4.example.com:1636/dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)" TLS

        Require valid-user
        Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Comment: Could you try on one line without the backslashes ? Or enclose each URL in double-quotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the ldaps:// on each line (except the first one) :

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://server1.example.com:1636 server2.example.com:1636 server3.example.com:1636 server4.example.com:1636/dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)" TLS
```

as specified in doc : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl

You may test after that with the baskslashes if it works.